# Checking which groups in pandas group by meet a certain condition

Tags: pandas

Suppose I have a pandas dataframe such as:

```
id | name

1    foo

1    bar

2    foo

3    bar
```

My goal is to get the % of distinct ids that have both 'foo' and 'bar'

So far I've attempted `df.groupby('id').name.nunique()`, I don't want a count of unique names, I want to search for foo and bar specifically.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
names_per_id = df.groupby('id')['name'].unique()
```

gets you a Series of lists, with:

```
id
1    [foo, bar]
2         [foo]
3         [bar]
```

from there we can get the ids which have both foo and bar:

```
foo_and_bar = names_per_id.apply(lambda row: ('foo' in row) and ('bar' in row))

1     True
2    False
3    False
```

finally, calculating the percentage you asked for:

```
pct = foo_and_bar.mean()

0.33333333333333331
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a general solution. Just replace the ['foo', 'bar'] list with a custom list of your choice.

```
res = df.groupby('id')['name'].agg(lambda s: np.all(np.in1d(['foo', 'bar'], s)))
```

Which outputs this:

```
     name
id       
1    True
2   False
3   False
```

Then just take the mean of this Series

```
res.mean()
```

Output

```
name    0.333333
dtype: float64
```

To keep it all in pandas do:

```
df.groupby('id')['name'].agg(lambda s: pd.Series(['foo', 'bar']).isin(s).all()).mean()
```